# Represent pointer as string and the other way around

Tags: c, pointers, mpi

I'm trying to write a program using MPI and I have a question that would help me a lot. Is it possible in MPI to send a pointer to another process in any way? What I want is to just send the pointer, not to copy the memory from one process to the other.

If that doesn't apply is it possible to represent a pointer as a string for example and then send it so that the receiving process can again cast it to pointer and have access to the memory pointed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pointer transfer shouldn't be the problem here. The problem is that the memory pointed to by the pointer needs to be available in both address spaces at the same location. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No, you cannot do that.

The explanation is that MPI processes are not guaranteed to share memory in any way. In fact most MPI implementations map MPI processes to actual OS processes, so that they don't share the same memory adress space. Plus you might want to run MPI applications on a cluster, in which case MPI processes are not even on the same hardware.

**EDIT:**

MPI2 introduces window operations (see e.g. `MPI_WIN_CREATE`), which mimic shared memory access. Your implementation might decide that if all processes are running on the same node, such window operations can be implemented using shared memory. But as always with MPI, you never have any guarantee how an operation will be implemented

Comment: I know about the different hardware but I was thinking of only exchanging pointer between processes in the same node. Thanks for the info though. At least I will not spend time at something that cannot be done.

Comment: You can't exchange a pointer between processes on the same node.  Well, you can, but such a pointer is meaningless.  On any modern operating system individual processes run in their own virtual address spaces.  If you wish to share memory between processes, look at POSIX shared memory functions (`shmget`, `shmat`, etc.) or memory-mapped files (`mmap`).  Note that most MPI implementations will use these methods behind the scenes.  So when you use `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`, and the processes share a node, the sender will copy the data to a shared buffer, and the receiver will copy out.